# How do we customize the "don't ask about" section on the about page?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, new-users

If you haven't noticed, the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) for every site got a makeover recently to better introduce people to asking and answering questions on the Stack Exchange network.

One of the sections on that page describes what is on and off-topic for [Japanese Language and Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/about), which currently displays a generic description.  However, [some](https://superuser.com/about) of the [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/about) [sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) have a more customized list of on-topic and off-topic topics.  For example, [the English site](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) has an item clarifying translations are off-topic, which would also apply to us too.

How would we go about updating the JLU about page?  Is this something our moderators can do, would we need the community team to intervene, or is this not even permitted for beta sites?

**Update:**  Official guidance [has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164778/what-should-we-put-on-our-about-page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your moderators can edit these:

[image: edit links for the two lists]

They can also tweak the wording on the top section as well, if needed:

[image: edit link for the top section]

If you have specific changes in mind, suggest them here on meta - after others have had a chance to provide feedback, the mods can make the changes.

Answer (score -1):

Shog9 just answered and we (editors) can indeed edit this section.

Maybe we can create a new question/CW (or should we just use the existing FAQ entry) to put together a concise list of examples for each...

Comment: I'd use a separate post. Also, I'll be sending some guidelines out for these shortly, but in the mean time: *try* to keep the sections short. It's practically a miracle if you can get new users to read anything at all; don't overload them with lengthy descriptions of every rule or debate; save those for /faq and meta...

Comment: @Shog9: most definitely. I think the current idea would be one line for "do ask" ("Ask about Japanese Language & Usage") and 3-4 lines with negative examples illustrating the more egregious and recurrent off-topic questions we get... Even though I don't think many people bother reading it, it still avoids cases of questions getting closed and people complaining that they read the FAQ/About/Whatever and did not see anything about it.

Comment: I don't think we need much in there, just some of the big categories we close a lot (translation comes to mind).  http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/796/162 might have some starting ideas: translations, resources, and culture seem to be the big three and I don't know if we even need to specifically call out all three.

Comment: Yeah, this should probably be discussed more on a separate post - though we can also possibly wait until the official guidelines are posted.